# TiDB CREATE FUNCTION returns error

Tags: mysql, distributed-database, tidb

I was running these codes in TiDB:

```
CREATE FUNCTION `FN_UP_TRADEDAY`(
endDay int(11),
upDays int(11),
marketx varchar(20)
) RETURNS int(11)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN

declare beginDay int(11);
declare days int(11) default upDays-1;

select
day into beginDay
from t_tradeday
where market = marketx and day <= endDay
order by day desc limit days, 1;

RETURN beginDay;
END;
```

But I can't create the function and get an error message: "[Err] 1105 - line 1 column 15 near `FN_UP_TRADEDAY`". Why?

Answer (score 1):

I did not find a specific description for creating functions in TiDB, so I can assume that the standard syntax of SQL is used.

So, you shouldn't use quotes `'`  in function name.
After returns there is string `READS SQL DATA`, seems like it's comment, so add `--` before, for escaping it.